# Centering absolute positionned flex children on IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On Chrome & Firefox, if a flexbox having `algin-items: center; justify-content: center;` has two absolute positioned children, the children will be both positioned at the center of their parent.

However, on IE11, the children will be both positioned at the bottom right of their parent.

**Example**

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">111</div>
  <div class="child2">2</div>
</div>
```

Result on Firefox : [image: Result on Firefox]

Result on IE11 : [image: Result on IE11]

**Question**

Is it possible to reproduce the Chrome & Firefox behavior on IE11 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if use position:relative/absolute and coordonates as in the olden days:

Démo to run with IE11 :  https://jsbin.com/puvuwidoyu/1/edit?html,css,output

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
}

.child1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green; 
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">111</div>
  <div class="child2">2</div>
</div>
```

since children are in absolute position, in IE11, what comes at center is the top left corner of the box no matter the size of the box.

Comment: Precisely, adding "top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;" on each children exactly reproduces the expected behavior. Thanks a lot !